# Safe way to create an "out of band" alternative value for a function argument in Python

Tags: python

I have a function like the following:

```
def do_something(thing):
    pass

def foo(everything, which_things):
    """Do stuff to things.

    Args:
        everything: Dict of things indexed by thing identifiers.
        which_things: Iterable of thing identifiers. Something is only
            done to these things.
    """

    for thing_identifier in which_things:
        do_something(everything[thing_identifier])
```

But I want to extend it so that a caller can `do_something` with everything passed in `everything` without having to provide a list of identifiers. (As a motivation, if `everything` was an opaque container whose keys weren't accessible to library users but only library internals. In this case, `foo` can access the keys but the caller can't. Another motivation is error prevention: having a constant with obvious semantics avoids a caller mistakenly passing the wrong set of identifiers in.) So one thought is to have a constant `USE_EVERYTHING` that can be passed in, like so:

```
def foo(everything, which_things):
    """Do stuff to things.

    Args:
        everything: Dict of things indexed by thing identifiers.
        which_things: Iterable of thing identifiers. Something is only
            done to these things. Alternatively pass USE_EVERYTHING to
            do something to everything.
    """

    if which_things == USE_EVERYTHING:
        which_things = everything.keys()
    for thing_identifier in which_things:
        do_something(everything[thing_identifier])
```

What are some advantages and limitations of this approach? How can I define a `USE_EVERYTHING` constant so that it is unique and specific to this function?

My first thought is to give it its own type, like so:

```
class UseEverythingType:
    pass

USE_EVERYTHING = UseEverythingType()
```

This would be in a package only exporting `USE_EVERYTHING`, discouraging creating any other `UseEverythingType` objects. But I worry that I'm not considering all aspects of Python's object model -- could two instances of `USE_EVERYTHING` somehow compare unequal?

Comment: While clunky, you could always call `foo(everything, everything.keys())`

Comment: @CameronRiddell That's a good approach, and in my toy example it would work. I'm trying to model a situation where `everything` might be an opaque container type (keys aren't accessible to library users). I'll edit the question to explain that.